Export Unreal assets and import into new project?
Imagine a scenario where you spend a ton of time creating a virtual world in Unreal but then decide you want to enlarge the landscape area.  Is there a way to export all the assets and their scaling/orientation/world position and pull those into the new project please?  The new map would have the same height map for the territory shared with the old map so the imported assets would sit correctly as long as an offset could be applied at import time.
Thanks!

The landscape and landscape layered objects(trees...) can be scaled via export and import of the layers.
For the rest of the objects, no simple translations exist.
You can learn the underlying map file structure and try to apply a bulk transformation. YMMV
